# Image appear when hover the text (html bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm coding my website with bootstrap (to make it responsive, and it's easier to update for me) and I'd like image to display when I over a text.
here's the code:

```html
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8" style="font-size: 24pt">
                <a href=""> INSTITUT HENRI POINCARRE, POSTER — 2017</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="image/ihp_poster01.JPG" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I would like the ihp_poster01.JPG image to appear when I hover "INSTITUT HENRI POINCARRE, POSTER — 2017". I've tried multiple things which didn't worked because the img and the text are not in the same `<div>`.
I guess I'll have to use Javascript, but I didn't found any JS for that :/ 
Can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: If you want it to happen only on hover of the link itself, then yes, you will have to use JS. If it is enough for your purposes that the whole outer div element triggers it, then CSS can handle that, using the adjacent sibling combinator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` events (using JavaScript of course) on `text` and toggle the `display` style of `image` accordingly...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var image = document.getElementById("img");
  name.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {   
    image.style.display = "block";
  });

  name.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {   
    image.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8" style="font-size: 24pt">
                <a href="" id="name"> INSTITUT HENRI POINCARRE, POSTER — 2017</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img style="display:none;" id="img" src="image/ihp_poster01.JPG" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Update:** To make this dynamic and handle different text with different images one can use `onmouseenter` & `onmouseleave` with common JS function, have a look at the snippet below:

```js
function toggleShow(elementId) {
  let el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  el.style.display = "block";
}

function toggleHide(elementId) {
  let el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  el.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8" style="font-size: 24pt">
                <a href="" onmouseenter="toggleShow('image1');" onmouseleave="toggleHide('image1');"> INSTITUT HENRI POINCARRE, POSTER — 2017</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img style="display:none;" id="image1" src="image/ihp_poster01.JPG" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
        
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8" style="font-size: 24pt">
                <a href="" onmouseenter="toggleShow('image2');" onmouseleave="toggleHide('image2');"> INSTITUT HENRI POINCARRE, POSTER — 2017</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img style="display:none;" id="image2" src="image/ihp_poster01.JPG" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Is there a way to use it for other text linked to other images without duplicating the script?